# Does someone know what's wrong in my if statement in C# Unity3D?

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine

I want to change the int speed value, but it doesn't work. Can someone help me? If you too have too few information, pls ask me.
This is my code:

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W)) {
        sprint1 = true;
    } else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W)){
        sprint1 = false;
    } 
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)){
        sprint2 = true;
    } else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift)){
        sprint2 = false;
    }
     if (sprint2 == false && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A) && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S) && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D)){
        speed = 0;
    } if (sprint2==false && (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))){

        speed = 4;

    }if (sprint1 == true && sprint2 == true && Scoped==true) {
        speed = 8;
    }
```

Comment: Is this code in the `Update()` loop?

Comment: Did you debug it?

Comment: If `Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W)` == false, could `Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W)` be false also? What about this: `sprint1 = Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W)`

Comment: Yes this is in the Update() loop, Smartis.

Comment: What do you mean Jerry Switalski?

Comment: Read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions *seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: @DaniëlvanderZwan take a look at [Debug](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.html) and [Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) if you don't know what debugging is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my own issue.
Thanks for all your comments, but I wanna show you my solution:

```
     if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
        sprint1 = true;
    } else {
        sprint1 = false;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftShift)) {
        sprint2 = true;
    } else {
        sprint2 = false;
    }
    if (sprint2 == false && sprint1==false && !(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) && !(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) && !(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D))){
        speed = 0;
    } if ((sprint1==true && sprint2==false) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)){

        speed = 4;

    }if (sprint1 == true && sprint2 == true && Scoped==true) {
        speed = 8;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (sprint2 == false && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A) && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S) && Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D)){
    speed = 0;
}
```

You will never enter in this particular case except if, during the exact same frame, you release W, A, S and D. Look at the [Input.GetKeyUp documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html):

> Returns true **during the frame** the user releases the key identified by the key KeyCode enum parameter.

You should organise it this way instead:

```
// If you are sprinting, set the speed to 8
if (sprint1 == true && sprint2 == true && Scoped==true) {
    speed = 8;
}
// Else if one of those keys has been touched during this frame, set the speed to 4
else if (sprint2==false && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))){
    speed = 4;
}
// Else, just set the speed to 0
else
    speed = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment you are the only one that helps me.

Answer (score 0):

If a key isn't down, it's up. No need to check for both. Anyway, this is the way I interpret your if.

```
sprint1 = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W);
sprint2 = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift);

if (sprint2)
{
   if (sprint1 && Scoped)
        speed = 8;
     else
        speed = 4; // do you want speed 0 or 4 if either of these others are false
}
else
{
    if (sprint1
     || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) 
     || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) 
     || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        speed = 4;     
    else
        speed = 0; 
}
```

What I think would work better, if I'm interpreting your desire, is

```
sprint1 = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W);
sprint2 = Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift);

if (sprint1 && sprint2 && Scoped)
     speed = 8;
else if (sprint1
     || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) 
     || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S) 
     || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    speed = 4;     
else
    speed = 0;
```

Comment: Actually your first statement (_If a key isn't down, it's up._) isn't strictly speaking true because of the way Unity handles key events. `GetKeyDown` is true during only **1 frame** (when user presses the key), `GetKeyUp` is also true during only **1 frame** (when user releases the key) and finally `GetKey` is true during **all the frames** where the key is hold down. But in this case using only `GetKey` should be enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing it so you don't have to make all these unnecessary flags for sprint.

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && Scoped)
        speed = 8;
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        speed = 4;
    else
        speed = 0;
```